# BigQuery standard SQL: how to group by an ARRAY field

Tags: arrays, string, group-by, google-bigquery, sql

My table has two columns, `id` and `a`. Column `id` contains a number, column `a` contains an array of strings. I want to count the number of unique id for a given array, equality between arrays being defined as "same size, same string for each index".

When using `GROUP BY a`, I get `Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed`. I can use something like `GROUP BY ARRAY_TO_STRING(a, ",")`, but then the two arrays `["a,b"]` and `["a","b"]` are grouped together, and I lose the "real" value of my array (so if I want to use it later in another query, I have to split the string).

The values in this field array come from the user, so I can't assume that some character is simply never going to be there (and use it as a separator).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of `GROUP BY ARRAY_TO_STRING(a, ",")` use `GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(a)`

so your query will look like below

```sql
#standardsql
SELECT 
  TO_JSON_STRING(a) arr,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY arr
```

You can test it with dummy data like below

```sql
#standardsql
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ["a,b", "c"] a UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, ["a","b,c"]
)
SELECT 
  TO_JSON_STRING(a) arr,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY arr
```

with result as

```sql
Row     arr             cnt  
1       ["a,b","c"]     1    
2       ["a","b,c"]     1
```

Update based on @Ted's comment

```sql
#standardsql
SELECT 
  ANY_VALUE(a) a,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(a)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Love how simple this solution is. Additional note: to preserve the array (and reuse it later), you can add `ANY_VALUE(a) a` to the final select (since they're all the same, it doesn't matter which one is chosen).

Comment: This seems to be the best workaround to date. For future folks, please add a +1 to this feature request so we can improve this experience. https://issuetracker.google.com/181880172

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use another separator than comma

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(a,"|")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! This suggestion will group together arrays like ["a", "b"] and ["a|b"], so this won't work. This is why the `TO_JSON_STRING` solution is clever: it will automatically escape the right content.