# How do I need to GROUP this query to be able to aggregate a MAX

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I need to `GROUP` this query (or can I `PARTITION` somehow), so that I get the `max(sample_date_time)` on line 4. This needs to be the `max` of *all* the records selected. I'm getting the error:

`SELECT list references .... label_list which is neither grouped nor aggregated ...`.

`label_list` has the data type of `RECORD (STRUCT)`. The `UNNEST` operator takes an `ARRAY` and returns a table, with one row for each element in the `ARRAY`

I looked at this - [BigQuery standard SQL: how to group by an ARRAY field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939402/bigquery-standard-sql-how-to-group-by-an-array-field) but it doesn't help me. The difference in my case is that I'm also selecting out of the `ARRAY`.

```
SELECT
  label_list,
  created_date_time,
  max(sample_date_time) AS sample_date_time_max, -- <-- HERE
  max(created_date_time) OVER (PARTITION By sample_date_time, finger_print_hash ORDER BY sample_date_time) AS created_date_time_max,
  sample_date_time,
  station,
  (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST(label_list)
  WHERE type = "CHL"
  ) as channel,
  value
FROM my.mart
WHERE sample_date_time BETWEEN "2019-07-25 23:00:00.000000+00:00" AND "2019-07-26 04:00:00.000000+00:00"
AND station = '[myGuid]'
AND uom = "[myUom]"
AND is_good_status = true
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(label_list)
```

---

Sample data:

```
Row station label_list.type label_list.name finger_print_hash   created_date_time   sample_date_time    time_zone   uom is_good_status
1   0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -7.97672E+16    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL PM25 HSPI                       

2   0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -1.35959E+18    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL PM10 HSPI                       

3   0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -6.25737E+17    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL NO2 HSPI                        

4   0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -4.68557E+18    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL Noise Level HSPI                        

5   0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -7.23989E+18    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSI TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL HSI                     

6   534e669069b74258b3386c482d11d139    STE Healthy School  -7.23989E+18    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Melbourne HSI TRUE
        STN Mock Station 1                      
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL HSI                     

7   534e669069b74258b3386c482d11d139    STE Healthy School  -4.68557E+18    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Melbourne HSPI    TRUE
        STN Mock Station 1                      
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL Noise Level HSPI                        

8   534e669069b74258b3386c482d11d139    STE Healthy School  -1.35959E+18    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Melbourne HSPI    TRUE
        STN Mock Station 1                      
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL PM10 HSPI                       

9   534e669069b74258b3386c482d11d139    STE Healthy School  -6.25737E+17    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Melbourne HSPI    TRUE
        STN Mock Station 1                      
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL NO2 HSPI                        

10  534e669069b74258b3386c482d11d139    STE Healthy School  -7.97672E+16    2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Melbourne HSPI    TRUE
        STN Mock Station 1                      
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL PM25 HSPI                       

11  0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  2.57256E+18 2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL O3 HSPI                     

12  534e669069b74258b3386c482d11d139    STE Healthy School  2.57256E+18 2019-07-26 05:15:03.097265 UTC  2019-07-26 04:00:00 UTC Australia/Melbourne HSPI    TRUE
        STN Mock Station 1                      
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL O3 HSPI                     

13  0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -4.68557E+18    2019-07-26 04:15:02.536014 UTC  2019-07-26 03:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL Noise Level HSPI                        

14  0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -1.35959E+18    2019-07-26 04:15:02.536014 UTC  2019-07-26 03:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL PM10 HSPI                       

15  0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -7.23989E+18    2019-07-26 04:15:02.536014 UTC  2019-07-26 03:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSI TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL HSI                     

16  0f97ae8cec364768b2df6fa98c20adb5    STE Healthy School  -7.97672E+16    2019-07-26 04:15:02.536014 UTC  2019-07-26 03:00:00 UTC Australia/Victoria  HSPI    TRUE
        STN API Test Pod                        
        RPT HSI                     
        INS Calculated                      
        CHL PM25 HSPI
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: what is `UNNEST`, its return type, since in your query it seems that this is giving one value only in any case....need details of this

Comment: can you clarify few things for me please - 1) what field is `STE Healthy School`? 2) why do you think you need `GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(label_list)`? what exactly you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: nevermind  - see my answer

Comment: Could you please add expected output along with the sample data. Your requirement is not clear.  I am confused because of the select query which has both max (sample_date_time), sample_date_time. There will be different sample_date_time for single label_list (if no what is the need of max(single label_list), which one do you want to select.

Comment: Never mind I got the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that below is what you really need

```
SELECT
  label_list,
  created_date_time,
  MAX(sample_date_time) OVER() AS sample_date_time_max, -- <-- HERE
  MAX(created_date_time) OVER (PARTITION By sample_date_time, finger_print_hash ORDER BY sample_date_time) AS created_date_time_max,
  sample_date_time,
  station,
  (
  SELECT name
  FROM UNNEST(label_list)
  WHERE type = "CHL"
  ) as channel,
  value
FROM my.mart
WHERE sample_date_time BETWEEN "2019-07-25 23:00:00.000000+00:00" AND "2019-07-26 04:00:00.000000+00:00"
AND station = '[myGuid]'
AND uom = "[myUom]"
AND is_good_status = true
```

and you don't need any GROUP BY here!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need that same `TO_JSON_STRING(label_list)` in select as well.

```
   Select TO_JSON_STRING(label_list)...
    ...group by 
     TO_JSON_STRING(label_list)
```

As label_list is unidentified in select for grouping

Comment: I can do this and it solves that error, and I can then GROUP BY all other columns in the query, but I then get an error on the `SELECT name
FROM UNNEST(label_list)
WHERE type = "CHL"`. I can't wrap that with `TO_JSON_STRING` as it needs to be preserved , for the `SELECT`

Comment: yes that inner select is independent so is not falling in sync try to add that channel query in group by as well and I dont understand why you need that subquery in select as it is indepemdent you can simply join it. Just do it like select all_columns except subquery group by json.... join subquery

Comment: how do I add the channel query in the group by? I can add 'channel' but I'm not sure about adding a query in a group by.

Comment: Try to join that subquery not in select itself